# How to find the minimum cost in a table by state and market in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a table that contains various values for State, Market, Length and Cost. I need to calculate a new measure showing the minimum cost available by state/market. I tried using Min with FILTER but the results are incorrect.

```
COST min =
CALCULATE (
    MIN ( Table1[COST] ),
    FILTER ( Table1, MIN ( Table1[LENGTH] ) ),
    Table1[LENGTH]    )
```

Table1:

```
STATE   MARKET  Vendor      LENGTH  COST
AL      BH      COMPANY_A   1000    2500 
AL      BH      COMPANY_B   1000    2250 
AL      BH      COMPANY_C   1000    2150 
AL      BH      COMPANY_D   1000    2000 
AL      BH      COMPANY_E   1000    2200 
AL      MO      COMPANY_A   1000    1000 
AL      MO      COMPANY_B   1000    1100 
AL      MO      COMPANY_C   1000    1400 
AL      MO      COMPANY_D   1000    1300
```

Expected Results:

```
STATE   MARKET  Vendor      LENGTH  COST  Min COST
AL      BH      COMPANY_A   1000    2500  2000
AL      BH      COMPANY_B   1000    2250  2000
AL      BH      COMPANY_C   1000    2150  2000
AL      BH      COMPANY_D   1000    2000  2000
AL      BH      COMPANY_E   1000    2200  2000
AL      MO      COMPANY_A   1000    1000  1000
AL      MO      COMPANY_B   1000    1100  1000
AL      MO      COMPANY_C   1000    1400  1000
AL      MO      COMPANY_D   1000    1300  1000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is both code for **Measure** and **Calculated Column** given below-

**Measure**

```
min_value_measure = 

var current_row_market = MIN(your_table_name[MARKET])
var current_row_length = MIN(your_table_name[LENGTH])

RETURN
CALCULATE(
    MIN(your_table_name[COST]),
    FILTER(
        ALL(your_table_name),
        your_table_name[MARKET] = current_row_market
        && your_table_name[LENGTH] = current_row_length 
    )
)
```

**Calculate Column**

```
min_value_column = 

var current_row_market = your_table_name[MARKET]
var current_row_length = your_table_name[LENGTH]

RETURN
CALCULATE(
    MIN(your_table_name[COST]),
    FILTER(
        ALL(your_table_name),
        your_table_name[MARKET] = current_row_market
        && your_table_name[LENGTH] = current_row_length
    )
)
```

Final Output-

[image]

Comment: Thank you. One additional question. Some states/market combinations have multiple Length values. I tried adding additional filters for Length but it didn't work.

Comment: Example of additional length values for the same state/market:
STATE MARKET VENDOR         LENGTH COST
AL         BH         COMPANY_A 5000 3000
AL         BH         COMPANY_B 5000 3100
AL         BH         COMPANY_C 5000 3200

Comment: Hi @Cainman, please check my updated answer.